# "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon" problem in Docker Ubuntu Container

Tags: docker

I have successfully installed Docker to Ubuntu 16. But to issue commands properly, I am adding `sudo` in front of all the docker commands such as `sudo docker pull wordpress`. Anyway, the `sudo` solved my `Cannot connect to daemon` problem. However, I needed to install docker into an ubuntu container, in the same way, I did for the host computer. I have researched and found the following solutions, but they didn't work for the container (I ran `apt-get update` before all these):

1. Use `sudo`. Didn't work.
2. `sudo usermod -aG docker <your username>`. Didn't work.
3. `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`. Didn't work.

About `sudo` command, though, it was not available in the container. So I had to run `apt-get install sudo`. Then, `sudo` started working but not docker. `docker` command itself works. But, when you make a request via Docker CLI to docker engine, it says it is not connected, or daemon is not working. Also, the default user in the docker ubuntu container is `root`. When you enter into the bash TTY, you see `root@[some number]`. I am using the following command to install docker: `sudo apt-get install docker.io`. I have followed the instructions here to install docker on my host Linux machine:

1. https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/
2. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04

But what really worked was:

https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

Comment: What it is the release of the Ubuntu container?

Comment: @Bidyut: It is ubuntu:16.04. You can check the container here https://store.docker.com/images/414e13de-f1ba-40d0-9867-08f2e5884b3f?tab=description

Comment: If you are runnning a ubuntu:16.04 inside the container, then inside you will be logged in as `root`. So you need not have to install `sudo`

Comment: @Bidyut: Thanks for your time, but it is not helpful. I already mentioned that in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Inside you Ubuntu:xenial container perform the following. [assuming you will be using the root user inside the container]

`apt-get update`

`apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates`

`apt-key adv \
               --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 \
               --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D`

`echo "<REPO>" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`

In place of  repo add the `deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main`

`apt-get update`

`apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) linux-image-extra-virtual`

`apt-get install docker-engine`

The above steps should install docker inside your container.

Please refer to this [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/)

Comment: Thanks, but these don't help. Perhaps, the containers miss something that is crucial to Docker.